# Filter the ArrayList using Guava Collections2.Filter in Android

Tags: java, android, collections, guava

Hi am Developing an application in which i want to sort the custom arrayList based on Price using Collections2.filter function(Guava library) but i didn't get the exact answer please help me to solve this problem.Thanks in advance.CustomArrayList is

```
ArrayList<Products> datas=new Arraylist<Products>();
Products products1=new Products();
products1.setname("data1");
products1.setprice(100);
datas.add(products1); 
Products products2=new Products();
products2.setname("data2");
products2.setprice(200);
datas.add(products2); 
Products products3=new Products();
products3.setname("data3");
products3.setprice(150);
datas.add(products3);
```

Now am trying to filter the list based on price.the code is

```
Collection<Products> data=Collections2.filter(datas,new customPredicate());
 private static class customPredicate implements Predicate<Products> {

        @Override
        public boolean apply(Products products) {
            return products.getPrice()>100&&products.getPrice()<150;
        }
    }
```

while use this code receive nothing in data.please help me...

Comment: Which product would you expect in the result?  Seems to be expected behaviour that the resulting collection is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the nature of your data. The products whose price is greater than 100 are product 2 and product 3. The products whose price is less than 150 is product 1. So upon applying these 2 conditions you get no result.
Try modifying your predicate condition to

```
 return products.getPrice()>100&&products.getPrice()<=150;
```

to atleast get product 3.

Comment: How can i get the details as same arraylist

Comment: what do you mean by "the details as same arraylist"?

Comment: Option to do what? Can you exactly tell me what you are looking for giving an example.